# Error: The trait `Handler<_>` is not implemented for `fn() -> HttpResponse

Tags: rust, actix-web

If I was to use this code on Actix Web 3 it would work, but I need to use the latest stable release... so 4^.

Here is the snippet in question (actually this is the entirety of my code):

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, ResponseError, Handler};


 fn hello_world() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello, Mr. World") }
 
 #[actix_web::main] async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
     HttpServer::new(move || App::new().route("hello", web::get().to(hello_world)))
         .bind("0.0.0.0:8000")?
         .run()
         .await
 }
```

Here is the error I get in version 4 or higher.

```
web::get().to(hello_world)))
    |                                                                  -- ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Handler<_>` is not implemented for `fn() -> HttpResponse {hello_world}`
    |                                                                  |
    |                                                                  required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `Route::to`
   --> /Users/xavierfontvillasenor/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-web-4.1.0/src/route.rs:211:12
    |
211 |         F: Handler<Args>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Route::to`
```

When I add the trait,

```
impl Handler<T> for HttpResponse {
    type Output = ();
    type Future = ();

    fn call(&self, args: T) -> Self::Future {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I get

```
impl Handler<T> for HttpResponse {
  |     -        ^ not found in this scope
  |     |
  |     help: you might be missing a type parameter: `<T>`
```

This works in V.3 why not now? What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not meant to implement `Handler` yourself, the issue is that handlers are required to be `async` functions, [see the docs for more details](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Handler.html#what-is-a-request-handler):

```rust
// 
async fn hello_world() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello, Mr. World")
}
```

Comment: Omg finally a response that makes sense! I am suffering with this for 3 days! These error messages were as bad as C++ templates in missdirection this time.

Answer (score 1):

Actix Web v4 removed the implementation of `Future` for `HttpResponse` causing this error. The compiler is correct but it's not the most useful error. TL;DR: **all** handlers must be async.

See [the migration guide](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/master/actix-web/MIGRATION-4.0.md#returning-httpresponse-synchronously)